# Wrapping a string literal type with backticks breaks when the type is generic

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I have two types:

```
type PathBare<T> = keyof T & string
type PathWrapped<T> = `${keyof T & string}`
```

Both just get the string keys of an object as a union. But one interpolates the string in a string literal and one does not.

These should be equivalent since the wrapping of the string literal should not change the type structurally. For example:

```
type ABC = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type A = ABC extends `${ABC}` ? true : false // true
```

But something strange happens when I pass these types a generic type instead of a concrete one:

```
type Named = { name: string, foo: string }

function foo<T extends Named>(arg: T): T {
    const a1: PathWrapped<Named> = 'name' // fine
    const a2: PathBare<Named> = 'name' // fine

    const b1: PathWrapped<T> = 'name' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '`${keyof T & string}`'.(2322)
    const b2: PathBare<T> = 'name' // fine

    return arg
}
```

Here using `T` should be exactly the same as using the type that constrains `T`, but it isn't. It seems to have completely forgotten what it is and is no longer assignable without a cast.

Why is that? What's going on here?

[See Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgITgJwgHgCoD4oC8UA1hCAPYBmU2UAZFAM7BoCWAdgOYBQoksCRAHU0cMJAAmOfEQAGAEgDepCtVoNmbLgF9Z3XuGgBBZAGFCUAORxLUAD5WARrYeWAxpYP8jFk+YgAHsAQ7BKMUAqKfrpQAPxQLACu0ABcUJRwADaM0AD0uQloyfp80ABycAC2EBIWilDsVRBpmhycADTp5OQtLG1Q2vqUiexuwKzk7F3kOFCBwaHhFdUSuAAU6Jxp2ACU21CK3FDHUG6TzFBwAIxp8EgiYpKYyzUyVo3VtvnpHBBHJ2d2Bc4AAmW6CVAYZ5NVYWSwfCBfAqUX76E6nc7AKCOG4Ce6icQ1aRwhFImiGKytLi2VjhdjkLFwRiMVicRqOTLQYDkBIUyyRFRUGj0Jh9HSySwAOjWIIAzCCQTt-sdARdHGC8Sh0Fg8CSmmSUew-sqoBhgIk0FNNtxBtxKN01vUEWlLAARRISRGde09JzoSydRxwABeaSS0G0O0lQeDUG+4aAA)

---

This is obviously a contrived example. The real use case from a library that is provided a type for a dotted path to identify nested fields by a string. I've reduced the types involved to find the minimal case that is causing the problem.

---

Motivating example:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'


type Named = { name: string }

function useFormWithNamedData<T extends Named>(data: T) {
    const { setValue } = useForm({ defaultValues: async () => data })

    useEffect(() => {
        setValue('name', 'foo') // Argument of type '"name"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Path<T>'.(2345)
    }, [])

    return {setValue}
}
useFormWithNamedData({ name: 'a', foo: 'b' }).setValue('foo', 'c') // good

function useFormWithNamedDataNonGeneric(data: Named) {
    const { setValue } = useForm({ defaultValues: async () => data })

    useEffect(() => {
        setValue('name', 'foo') // fine
    }, [])

    return {setValue}
}
useFormWithNamedDataNonGeneric({ name: 'a', foo: 'b' }).setValue('foo', 'c') // error, needs to work
```

Here the `setValue` function from `react-hook-form` expects a string path to the property to set. But `'name'` is not allowed, even though `'name'` is part of the constraint so it must exist. It seems like the compiler should know that.

And I can't use the constraint directly in the call to `useForm` since I want to return data of a type that depends on `T`. In this case `setValue` will accept `'name'` as well as whatever other paths were passed in on this object.

In trying to figure out why, I reduced the problem to the what seems like the top part of this question.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&install-plugin=typescript-playground-link-shortener#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCiAzb6DG8AvnNlBCHAORToCGhVAUKJLIihgGLSUlkVqtBjAC0ACwgQA1qOy9mTJjACeYdHABydEOgAmcALwcAdjvQAuOKhhRgJgOZwiS7MhOFgEE53Q8oIADqwDDi2rp6ACJ0MHQAPAAqcOgAHjDoJnqoWuZ6AHwAFHoxdFYJAJSITHA1cPjeNhwYMABqdAA2yBokxmh+vAVIeujYdMjtrR1dqFZ0qCoecAWVhnlwxbHO5Uq1vjh4hAXLRmsI1bu1zW2d6AVUZrpUADTU8hBUlQD0n3AAglAOZC6EzwCDYOCqdTUABED3Q0KocGA2RMEHgc1QwAcZgARu0NDAIHAwHQoOZ0lA4GCIWoNFQAAoxcSJPJUAB0BQATABmAAsAFZtrsiC8ANoAXW25xqtBgyCgPgQVym6BcLj6-iCITCuWisUGcDhViodGepCkxpxiKI5TZypudzeZqo+A+cG+cAcUj0rncnm8vk1wVC4X0eromm8AHEMug7PgiiUrKG9JUzrt6iZGkh7V1nEZAwMhiMxhNrtNZvNFsdVusSlsdrU+vsCDAjitTtKLrnbvdzM6nV8fth7OguyK4BKpbtZfLFT21UwNbxgzqIuHIyYYyY48AE0gjdRTS83pbrbae46pM7XUPklByFAXjv9NlCXAAO7QaRAA)

Comment: @jcalz Well I guess I assumed that inside a scope that declare a generic `T` basically equivalent to the constraint of `T`, since in that scope, that's the only information we know about `T`. Therefore the difference is surprising.

Comment: @jcalz I updated the question with the motivating example. It shows how I need the generic `T`, but then also need to be able to call `setValue` in that scope with the properties that must exist on `T` because `T extends Named`, and then return `setValue` with a type that is fully prepped for `T` and not just the constraint.

Comment: It's not at all really react related. And I guess I'm a bit too dense today to understand exactly what that first comment means. But given the type that's doing this is coming from a library we don't have direct control over, it does sound like the best course is an assertion to tell the compiler what it's not able to figure out. I was just surprised by that `'name'` was assignable to the paths of `{ name: string }`, but not assignable to the paths of `T` when `T extends { name : string }`. If you could elaborate on your first comment, I'd love to accept that as an answer.

Comment: Ok, yeah I think I got you. So some transformations of types just don't have a code path to resolve them against what _can_ be known about them when they are generic, and interpolated string literal types is one of those cases? And that's because it's hard to transform an unknown (generic) type and track the pattern of how that transform affected the parts of that unknown type, since it has no info about the unknown parts of that type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is considered a bug as per [microsoft/TypeScript#56582](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56582), and it was fixed in [microsoft/TypeScript#56598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56598), which will be [released with TypeScript 5.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-4-rc/#improved-checking-against-template-strings-with-interpolations).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.5.0-dev.20240222#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgITgJwgHgCoD4oC8UA1hCAPYBmU2UAZFAM7BoCWAdgOYBQoksCRAHU0cMJAAmOfEQAGAEgDepCtVoNmbLgF9Z3XuGgBBZAGFCUAORxLUAD5WARrYeWAxpYP8jFk+YgAHsAQ7BKMUAqKfrpQAPxQLACu0ABcUJRwADaM0AD0uQloyfpe0ABycAC2EBIWilDsVRBpmhycADTp5OQtLG1Q2vqUiexuwKzk7F3kOFCBwaHhFdUSuAAU6Jxp2ACU21CK3FBQbpPMUHAAjGnwSCJikpjLNTJWjdW2+ekcEEcnZ8ALgAmG6CVAYJ5NVYWSzvCCfAqUH76Y6ndjnRzXAR3UTiGrSGFwhHfdjQODhKg0ADKAFYAHQAFgA1H80RiQdiUOgsHhCU1iUjSSioBhgIk0FNNtxBtwgA)